# How do I convert a 32-bit binary string to float in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm receiving a binary string which represents a group of 32-bit floats.  It is reported from series of pairs of 16-bit MODBUS registers whereby the first register represents the lower bits and the second register represents the higher bits.  I am able to, in a horrifically ugly manner, rearrange the registers then decode to a float.  I'd like this to be quite a bit more attractive, but I'm failing at the task.  Essentially, I'm unpacking the string to a hex string array, converting to string, slicing the high bits and putting them in front of the low bits, then converting it to integer base 16, packing it to a 32 bit integer, unpacking to a float, then selecting the first value in the array.  If you'll excuse me, that last sentence makes me need to weep.  Without further ado:

```
def read_dual_input_registers(addr, npairs)
  @values = Array.new
  result = <binary-string-returned-here>.unpack('H*').to_s

  npairs.to_i.times do 
    register = result.slice!(4..7) + result.slice!(0..3)
    @values.push([register.to_i(16)].pack('L').unpack('F')[0])
  end
  @values
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
t = <binary-string-returned-here>
result = (t[2..3] + t[0..1]).unpack('F')[0]
```

Comment: It does not.  The binary string returned is the portion my debug shows as [4f][76][43][c0].  Ignore the leading and trailing portions.
Rx (9 bytes): [02][03][04][4f][76][43][c0][0f][5d]
=> 1.05342283266357e+33

Comment: The correct response to the above would have been: >> ['43c04f76'.to_i(16)].pack('L').unpack('F')[0]
=> 384.620788574219

Comment: Endianness.  You were essentially correct: (result[2..3] + result[0..1]).unpack('g') works.  A million thanks.